# Параллельная реализация сортировки Хоара

Tags: c++, openmp

Есть задание сделать параллельную реализация быстрой сортировки, но у меня получается так, что параллельный алгоритм работает в разы медленнее чем последовательный. Думаю что где-то накосячил с рекурсией в секциях. Был бы очень благодарен за помощь

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

const int n = 1000;
int first, last;

void quicksort(int* mas, int first, int last, int d = 0) {
    int mid, count, v;
    int f = first, l = last;
    mid = mas[(f + l) / 2];
    do {
        while (mas[f] < mid)
            f++;
        while (mas[l] > mid)
            l--;

        if (f <= l) {
            count = mas[f];
            mas[f] = mas[l];
            mas[l] = count;
            f++;
            l--;
            d++;
        }
    } while (f < l);

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) if (d == 1)
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            if (first < l)
                quicksort(mas, first, l);
            //cout << "I am proc number: " << omp_get_thread_num() << " " << endl;
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            if (f < last)
                quicksort(mas, f, last);
            //cout << "I am proc number: " << omp_get_thread_num() << " "<< endl;
        }
    }

    //cout << "d = " << d;
}


void main() {
    int* A = new int[n];

    /*cout<<"Initial massive: ";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        A[i]=rand()%100;
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }*/

    first = 0;
    last = n - 1;
    double start_time = clock();
    quicksort(A, first, last);

    /*cout<<endl<<"Result massive: ";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) cout<<A[i]<<" ";*/

    double end_time = clock();
    cout << endl;
    double time = end_time - start_time;
    printf("%f", (double)time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    delete[] A;
    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ошибки в коде в вопросе

С приведённым кодом много проблем, как методологических, так и алгоритмических, и, само собой, в работе с `openmp`. Вот то что бросилось в глаза:

- Массив слишком мал, чтобы оценить или получить выгоду от распараллеливания
- `clock ()` возвращает процессорное время всего процесса, что **непригодно** для замера времени выполнения многопоточного приложения.
- Диапазоны рекурсивных вызовов могут пересекаться. В однопоточном режиме это можно простить, но в многопоточном это фатально.
- Из-за бестолкового использования счётчика глубины рекурсии (`d`) код всегда работает в один поток (с затратами на вызовы openmp).
- Даже если бы оно работало правильно, оно создавало бы не больше двух потоков, если не вызвать `omp_set_nested(1)` или не передать в среду переменную `OMP_NESTED=true`.

### Как следует делать

Хотя распараллеливание при рекурсии и можно ограничить средствами `sections`, эффективнее это будет сделать с помощью заданий ([`task`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbclx01/prag_omp_task.htm)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <utility>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

constexpr size_t n = 1024*1024*128;
//const int n = 16;

static size_t minParallelSize = 128*1024;
static unsigned maxParallelDepth = 4;


void serialQuicksort(int* mas, size_t first, size_t last) {
    int mid;
    size_t f = first, l = last;
    mid = mas[(f + l) / 2];
    while (1) {
        while (mas[f] < mid) { ++f; };
        while (mas[l] > mid) { --l; };

        if (f >= l) { break; }

        std::swap (mas[f++], mas[l--]);
    }

    size_t part = l;

    if (first < part)
        serialQuicksort(mas, first, part);
    if (part+1 < last)
        serialQuicksort(mas, part+1, last);
}

void quicksort(int* mas, size_t first, size_t last, unsigned d = 0) {
    int mid;
    size_t f = first, l = last;
    mid = mas[(f + l) / 2];
    while (1) {
        while (mas[f] < mid) { ++f; };
        while (mas[l] > mid) { --l; };

        if (f >= l) { break; }

        std::swap (mas[f++], mas[l--]);
    }

    size_t part = l;

    #pragma omp task if (d <maxParallelDepth && (last - first) > minParallelSize)
    {
        if (first < part)
            quicksort(mas, first, part, d+1);
    }
    #pragma omp task if (d <maxParallelDepth && (last - first) > minParallelSize)
    {
        if (part+1 < last)
            quicksort(mas, part+1, last, d+1);
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
}


int main() {
    int rc = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    int* parallelA = new int[n];
    int*   serialA = new int[n];

    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int r = rand();
        parallelA[i] = r;
        serialA[i]   = r;
    }

    [[maybe_unused]] unsigned num_threads = std::min<unsigned> (
                n / minParallelSize / 2,
                1 << (maxParallelDepth-1) ); 

    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_threads)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        { quicksort(parallelA, 0, n-1); }
    }
    auto end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> time = end_time - start_time;

    fprintf(stderr, "Complete parallel qsort in %-8.3lfms\n", time.count ());

    start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    serialQuicksort(serialA, 0, n-1);
    end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    time = end_time - start_time;
    fprintf(stderr, "Complete   serial qsort in %-8.3lfms\n", time.count ());

    for (size_t i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        if (parallelA[i]>parallelA[i+1]) {
            rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
            fprintf (stderr, "Array is not sorted A[%zd]=%d (>) A[%zd]=%d\n", 
                     i, parallelA[i], i+1, parallelA[i+1] );
            break;
        }
    }

    delete[] parallelA;
    delete[] serialA;

    return rc;
}
```

Типовой результат:

```
Complete parallel qsort in 6492.260ms
Complete   serial qsort in 13031.032ms
```

Т.е. прирост производительности составляет ±2 раза на 4-х рельных ядрах.

### Дальнейшая оптимизация:

Приведённый пример слабо оптимизирован и требует более тонкой настройки. Во-первых требуется подобрать такие магические константы, как `minParallelSize` и `maxParallelDepth`, ограничивающих соответственно минимальный размер массива и максимальную глубину рекурсии для которых будут создаваться задания для параллельного выполнения. Они устанавливаются исключительно экспериментально.

Далее нужно подобрать формулу для `num_threads` в `main()`. Дело в том, что, судя по всему (только моё предположение), переключение потоков в ядре происходит несколько быстрее нежели переключение заданий в реализации OpenmMP(по крайней мере в связке linux/gomp). В результате простое избыточное увеличение количества потоков даёт прирост до 25%. Текущая формула чисто умозрительная. Помимо прочего она, вероятно, должна зависеть от числа доступных процессоров.

Кроме того значительный прирост производительности дадут вызовы не-параллельных версий по вышеозначенным условиям, вместо простой рекурсии; а также использование других методов сортировки для малых массивов (пирамида? шелл? слияние?).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, Вы просто неправильно измеряете результаты. Недостаточно прогнать код один раз так, другой иначе и сказать, что лучше. Нужно зациклить оба варианта минимум по 1000 раз, потом уже сверять средние результаты. Вот мой слегка модифицированный вариант (создание потоков происходит независимо от глубины рекурсии):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

const int total_count = 50000;
const int n = 1000;
int first, last;

void quicksort(int* mas, int first, int last, int d=0) {
    int mid, count, v;
    int f = first, l = last;
    mid = mas[(f + l) / 2];
    do {
        while (mas[f] < mid)
            f++;
        while (mas[l] > mid)
            l--;

        if (f <= l) {
            count = mas[f];
            mas[f] = mas[l];
            mas[l] = count;
            f++;
            l--;
            d++;
        }
    } while (f < l);

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            if (first < l)
                quicksort(mas, first, l, d);
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            if (f < last)
                quicksort(mas, f, last, d);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int* A = new int[n];
    double total_time = 0;

    for (int once = 0; once < total_count; once++) {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            A[i] = rand() % 10000;
        }
        first = 0;
        last = n - 1;
        double start_time = clock();
        quicksort(A, first, last);
        double end_time = clock();
        total_time += end_time - start_time;
    }

    total_time /= total_count;
    printf("Avg.time: %f", (double)total_time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    delete[] A;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

В итоге, у меня оба варианта сводятся ровно к `0.000044`. Это, конечно, не выигрыш, но и не проигрыш.

Comment: @etki Нет, создание массива не измеряется – `start_time` и `end_time` идут непосредственно до и после сортировки. А массив да, можно и побольше бы взять, но я запускал код в облачном сервисе, там ограничения по памяти/времени. Главное – указать вектор дальнейших действий для автора вопроса `(:`

Comment: При параллельной реализации на массиве до 1000000 элементов время приблизительно равно, а потом начинается вообще кошмар. В тот момент когда последовательный алгоритм считает где-то за 13 секунд, параллельный настолько долго что у меня не хватало терпения дождаться результата

Comment: @mhz параллелизм не всегда выигрышен – при росте числа потоков/ядер всё больше ресурсов начинает тратиться на синхронизацию потоков исполнения. На некоторых алгоритмах/процессорах такие нюансы делают параллелизм вообще невыгодным. 
[Примерный график производительности](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/_processed_/a/9/csm_02AmdahlsLaw_bcb8c8b2c6.jpg).